# REST Integration with Public Site usage with Guest License

Tags: rest-api, integration, site.com

As per the latest release in Salesforce i.e., the Summer '20, Salesforce is going to relegate all the permissions of the Guest user license i.e, view all and modify all will be removed. I have a intgeration set up with Xero and hence I would like to know the alternative approaches I can use to sought put this issue.

Comment: You can use guest sharing rules to provide the access.

Comment: @manjit5190, can you explain in detail?

Comment: I don't think a complete answer can be given without knowing all of the required access for your integration. The better pattern is not to use a Guest Site User for an integration - that's a fairly risky approach that makes it hard for you  to follow the principle of least privilege and requires you to reimplement authentication instead of just using OAuth.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replies. I was able to achieve the same with the use of connected apps and make a rest API callout to another class within the same org,